# I have a list that stores PointD objects. PointD is a class for storing x and y in double

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I use the distinct method for my user defined object So that no two points are the same?

---

//This is my class

```
class PointD
{
    private double m_dPointDx;
    private double m_dPointDy;
}
```

This is my List that contain PointD objects

```
List<PointD> listPoints = new List<PointD>();
listPoints.Add(new PointD(10,45));
listPoints.Add(new PointD(20,65));
listPoints.Add(new PointD(10,45));
```

Now how to distinct the list so that no two points are same ?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent adding duplicate points or select the distinct points after they have been added?

Comment: select the distinct points after they have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would redefine the `PointD` class like this:

```
class PointD
{
    public double M_dPointDx;
    public double M_dPointDy;
    public PointD(double x, double y)
    {
        M_dPointDx = x;
        M_dPointDy = y;
    }
}
```

Define the following class which implements the `IEqualityComparer<PointD>` interface:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<PointD>
{
    public bool Equals(PointD x, PointD y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the PointD' properties are equal. 
        return x.M_dPointDx==y.M_dPointDx && x.M_dPointDy==y.M_dPointDy;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

    public int GetHashCode(PointD pointD)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(pointD, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the M_dPointDx field if it is not null. 
        int hashX = pointD.M_dPointDx == null ? 0 : pointD.M_dPointDy.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the M_dPointDy field. 
        int hashY = pointD.M_dPointDy.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the PointD. 
        return hashX ^ hashY;
    }
}
```

Then, you have this usage:

```
List<PointD> listPoints = new List<PointD>();
listPoints.Add(new PointD(10, 45));
listPoints.Add(new PointD(20, 65));
listPoints.Add(new PointD(10, 45));

var distinctItems = listPoints
    .Distinct(new MyComparer())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, Right now I am at home will check your code tommorow.I also searched the net for IEqualityComparer which you have implemented above and got the following program which addresses similar issue. The Link is : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx Hope this would help future programmers.